# Ubuntu reboot fails - reboot or select proper boot device

Tags: 16.04

My Ubuntu 16.04 LTS dektop was working well, suddenly when I restarted today, it fails to restart or reboot.
Stuck in reboot or select proper boot device.
I did the boot repair - and following is the url.
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25799792

Answer (score 0):

Is your (hard or whatever, flash, etc) system drive there? Does it work?

From the boot repair output, the only drives are an ISO in sr0 (dvd) and the live filesystem's ram drives...

I think these next two are EFI related & only 1.5GB, too small for a system drive:

```
1:2048B:6143B:4096B::Apple:; 
2:1539MB:1542MB:2392kB::EFI:;]
```

So, looks like it can't see your system drive, it must be gone / unplugged or broken :(